# How to smoothly change <img src="..." /> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm now doing something like :

```
$img.hover(function(){$(this).attr('src','1.jpg')},function(){$(this).attr('src','2.jpg')});
```

Which is not smooth,because it takes quite some time to load an image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about pre-loading your images when the page loads:

```
$(function () {
  var preloadImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'];

  $.each(preloadImages, function () {
    $('<img/>').attr('src', this);
  });

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Do you prefer this method as opposed to `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'preloadMe.jpg'`? Just wondering as I've always used my example and havn't considered other options.

Comment: @alex, Well, the two ways are equivalent, when I have no jQuery on hand, I use something like your example or simply something like this: `(document.createElement('img')).src = 'preloadMe.jpg';`

Answer (score 5):

Change that to a background image with both the images combined and change the background position dynamically.

Use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

If you need to stick with an image itself then preload the two images and then it will take the second image from the cache which won't cause the delay.

[Preloading Images With CSS](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol6/css_no18.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Load image and swap when done](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/) or [Preload image when page load](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html).

Answer (score 0):

perload the image and put it in div that have a opacity:0;height:0;width:0;

```
preload_url = $(this).data('hover_image');
$('body').append('<div style="opacity:0;height:0;width:0"><img src="'+preload_url+'"></div>');
```